# BQ - Join two structs without duplicates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to do something like this:

```
id
addresess<struct>
    id
    street
    number
    city
contracts<struct>
    other_id 
    agency_code
    latitude
    longitude
    payments<struct>
            id_payment
            payment
            date_of_payment
```

So far I made two separate tables, the address one

```
create table address_table as 
select id,
    array_agg(struct(
                    a.street as street,
                    a.number as number,
                    a.city as city 
    )) as addresess
    from a_address_table
    group by id
```

and the contracts one:

```
create table contracts_table as 
select id,
    array_agg(struct(
                    a.other_id as other_id,
                    a.agency_code as agency_code,
                    p.payments              --ommited the payments struct
    )) as contracts
    from a_contracts_table a left join payments_temp p on a.other_id=p.other_id
    group by id
```

Lets say I have a person with id=5 who has one address and 3 contracts (3 different other_id); I have my final table like this:

```
create table final_table as 
    select b.id, 
    array_agg(ad) as addresess,
    array_agg(co) as contracts
    from address_table a cross join unnest(a.addresess) ad with offset d1 
    left outer join contracts_table b on a.id=b.id, unnest(b.contracts) co with offset s1
    where d1=s1 
    group by id
```

The problem is, in the example with someone with just one address, I see the address record three times because of the three contracts

This is what I'm getting:

```
id  address.street address.number address.city contracts.other_id contracts.agency_code payments.money
5   street1         520             Manchester  80                  agencyone           500
    street1         520             Manchester                                          600
    street1         520             Manchester                                          400
                                                                                        100
                                                                                        200
                                                50                  agencytwo           350
                                                                                        150
                                                                                        100
                                                20                  agencythree         50
                                                                                        20
                                                                                        60
```

and I need this

```
id  address.street address.number address.city contracts.other_id contracts.agency_code payments.money
5   street1         520             Manchester  80                  agencyone           500
                                                                                        600
                                                                                        400
                                                                                        100
                                                                                        200
                                                50                  agencytwo           350
                                                                                        150
                                                                                        100
                                                20                  agencythree         50
                                                                                        20
                                                                                        60
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have any reason to flatten arrays and aggregate them again ? Just `select a.id, addresses, contracts from address_table a left join contracts_table b on a.id = b.id`  isn't enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already aggregated your tables, you can just join them

```
create table final_table as 
select id, 
    a.addresess,
    b.contracts
from address_table a 
left outer join contracts_table b
  using(id)
```